# How to search through a nested field which is a list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I would like to search for a pattern, for each element in a list, which is a nested field in MongoDB. 
I have an Object, which contains authors list, which can contain from 0 to N elements. I want to retrieve objects whose authors met the search pattern. An author contains 4 fields, I only scan for names and surnames. How to do that within MongoDB query?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like:

```
db.article.find({$and:[{"authors.givenNames":"javier"},{"authors.familyName":"XXXXX"}]})
```

You can read about it in [This link](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index)

Hope it helps you!